# Why using computation() scheduler in nested streams causes deadlocks?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Recently I was writing a bit of complex RX-based flow, and found it always generates deadlocks in specific situation. I took me hours to find out what's wrong and it seems it can be reproduced in this simple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
        .flatMap(x -> Observable.fromIterable(produceMultiple(x)))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .subscribe(System.out::println);

    Thread.sleep(50_000);
}

private static List<Integer> produceMultiple(int x) {
    return Observable.range(1, x)
        .flatMap(y -> Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                return 10 * x + y;
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        ).toList().blockingGet();
}
```

This program should print following values: 11, 21, 22, 31, 32, 33, ...,  99. In general, value can be represented as XY. The order of values in each group X can be random, but groups should be ordered ascending. New group shouldn't be emitted if previous is still calculating (that was my original case).

The problem is, if you run this code, you'll only see output from first few elements - I believe it is correlated to number of processors, because computation() scheduler uses fixed thread pool size.

Do you know why it works that way? It seems odd, because main chain of numbers (1, 2, 3, ..) is processed on single thread from the pool and the other threads should be free each time produceMultiple finishes its job with blockingGet().

If you modify any subscribeOn() providing different schedulers (or one is computation() and second is different) everything works ok. Moreover, if I create Scheduler from custom thread pool executor (bound to 4 threads) it still works!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `blockingGet` on a `computation` scheduler as you may block a backing thread used by other parts of your code. You don't even have to use it in your code, just return `Observable` from the `produceMultiple`:

```java
static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
        .flatMap(x -> produceMultiple(x))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .subscribe(System.out::println);

    Thread.sleep(50_000);
}

static Observable<Integer> produceMultiple(int x) {
    return Observable.range(1, x)
        .flatMap(y -> Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                return 10 * x + y;
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        );
}
```

Comment: Your solution is ok, but it changes a bit my assumptions about group processing. However, if you change `flatMap`  in main method  into `concatMap`, everything works as intented. Nevertheless, I still don't know why the sample code I posted above doesn't reach the end... It's not that "it may block", it always blocks in the same moment. It looks like computation scheduler is filled with tasks from `produceMultiple` and these tasks never release the scheduler, even when they invoke `onComplete`.